# authorised access to externally hosted files

Tags: security, file, hosting, authorization, cloud

I'm looking for a solution to what I would have thought is an fairly common industry scenario, but I may be approaching it incorrectly.

I have a website which includes areas for member file uploads. The files (pdfs, mp3s docs etc) can then be shared with other members according to various authorisation criteria. I'd like the files to be stored and served over a cloud server such as rackspace file cloud, and to be separate from the website in order that file streaming traffic does not affect web performance, and also so that the site doesn't need to be hosted on an expensive cloud package.

I need a solution to ensure that the urls for files on the file server require authorisation checks for access. I had hoped to install a script on rackspace file cloud to do an API check back to my website before serving, but apparently rackspace file cloud doesn't allow this.

Imagine a site where you purchase mp3s. I've done this before where the mp3 file is streamed via a php web script which checks you've paid, but I want don't want my web server to be affected by streaming large or frequently downloaded files.

Surely this is common and simple?!

Comment: As you already know, you can provision simple static ACL rules with both the Rackspace and Amazon cloud storage products, but you apparently can't specify something dynamic that will check with your server on each access. I would also very much like to know the answer to your question. The only workaround I can think of is to make the URLs secret, reveal them to authorized users, and rename them once in a while.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Celada. I'm totally baffled that hosting companies aren't all over this. As I say, it's very common for sites to have files as saleable assets. How do all of those thousands of sites who have pay and download, do this? I can't believe they all have files and web scripts hosted together?

Comment: Update: I still don't have a solution for this, although rackspace do say that they trialling some solutions for providing authorisation options for cloud files. In the mean time, I'm going to plump for putting the whole site onto rackspace cloud servers.

Comment: Pre-signed urls vended to your customer would work with S3 - they are time bound, and if the customer shares them, anyone could potentially use that link.

Answer (score 0):

Rackspace [TempURL](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/TempURL-d1a4450.html) functionality might fit these needs.

Then the architecture of the solution looks like:

- Host authorization/roles/permissions code on your (expensive) application server hosting
- Upon successful auth for the resource, [generate a TempURL](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Create_TempURL-d1a444.html) the expires after a few seconds
- Use a 302 redirect to direct the client to TempURL for the resource

Now, with this solution there's nothing preventing a malicious authorized user from distributing the URL for multiple downloads within the small window that it's active. You can decide whether that's a problem or not given that you're intended to serve it to them and they could just as easily distribute it out of band afterward.