# Temporary access to an externally hosted file

Tags: cloud, storage

Hey everyone there was a question that was never really answered, it was posted roughly two years ago on stackoverflow:

[authorised access to externally hosted files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824829/authorised-access-to-externally-hosted-files)

I am hosting a domain for my friend and he is selling a virtual copy of dvd, zip files. Is there a file hosting website or cloud based service that allows you to give a person access to a file and prevent the general public from being able to access it without an access key(given upon purchase) or similar method.

Thanks

Aiden

Answer (score 0):

Give the file a complex random name (something that can not be guessed) and, of course, make sure directory listing is disabled.  When someone buys a "file" (whatever it is) give the link to the buyer.